# How to prevent Admob ad ids from leaked by android hackig app

Tags: java, android, security, admob, android-security

I have developed an android app. All the things are working fine but the main problem is, using the [Hack App Data](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-hack-app-data-public-pro-version-t3118517) anyone can see the ad codes which is a very dangerous threat.

Now how can i prevent hack app to open my application or edit my application data or how can i prevent hack app data to access this sensitive information?

note: I have turned off `android:exported="false"` and also add `<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:name="apricot.com.newshunt"/>` to my menifest file

Answer (score 1):

you can set the Copy Protection to `On` in the **Android Market upload page.** It's near the bottom. I doubt it is fool-proof but it can help keep some of the people likely to do this from being able to.

You should add the view in Java instead of XML and obfuscate your code.

Comment: I think hack app data is doing memory menupulation. thats why it is getting the adcodes. I have called all the ads by Java.